# How to use scanCrop property on a custom sized ZBarReaderView with an overlay

Tags: ios, objective-c, zbar

I have a ZBarReaderView embedded in a viewController and I would like to limit the area of the scan to a square in the middle of the view. I have set the resolution of the camera to 1280x720. Assuming the device is in Portrait Mode, I calculate the normalized coordinates only using the cameraViewBounds, which is the readerView's bounds and the overlayViewFrame which is the orange box's frame, as seen in this screenshot - https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uhuE.png . Here is what I have so far:

```
    self.cameraView.session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720;

    //Set CameraView's Frame to fit the SideController's Width
    CGPoint origin = self.cameraView.frame.origin;
    float cameraWidth = self.view.frame.size.width;
    self.cameraView.frame = CGRectMake(origin.x, origin.y, cameraWidth, cameraWidth);

    //Set CameraView's Cropped Scanning Rect
    CGFloat x,y,width,height;
    CGRect cameraViewBounds = self.cameraView.bounds;
    CGRect overlayViewFrame = self.overlay.frame;

    y =  overlayViewFrame.origin.y / cameraViewBounds.size.height;
    x =  overlayViewFrame.origin.x / cameraViewBounds.size.width;
    height = overlayViewFrame.size.height / cameraViewBounds.size.height;
    width = overlayViewFrame.size.width / cameraViewBounds.size.width;
    self.cameraView.scanCrop = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
    NSLog(@"\n\nScan Crop:\n%@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.cameraView.scanCrop));
```

As you can see in the screenshot, the blue box is the scanCrop rect, what I want to be able to do is have that blue box match the orange box. Do I need to factor in the resolution of the image or the image size when calculating the normalized values for the scanCrop?

I cannot figure out what spadix is explaining in this comment on sourceforge:
"So, assuming your sample rectangle represents screen points in portrait orientation and using the default 640x480 camera resolution, your scanCrop rectangle would be {75/w, 38/320., 128/w, 244/320.}, where w=480/(320*640.) is the major dimension of the image in screen points." and here:
"assuming your coordinates refer to points in portrait orientation, using the default camera image size, located at the default location and taking into account that the camera image is rotated:
scanCrop = CGRectMake(50/426., 1-(20+250)/320., 150/426., 250/320.)"

He uses the values 426 and 320 which I am assuming have to do with the image size but in one of his comments he mentions that the resolution is 640x480. How do I factor in the image size to calculate the correct rect for scanCrop?